# SQL Function to replace space with , and | with space and copy text (SQL Server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am just a starter in SQL Scripting and I have a field `A` containing string values in the following format:

```
X1|Y1 X2|Y2 X3|Y3 X4|Y4 X5|Y5
```

I am trying to create a function to replace the **space** with , and then replace | with a space. After that, put , at the end of the string and paste the chars before the first space comma in the string "X1 Y1" to the end of the text. 
So, the resulting text in the field `B` will be as follows:

```
X1 Y1,X2 Y2,X3 Y3,X4 Y4,X5 Y5,X1 Y1
```

Fields A and B are of type: ntext

Note: I tried to use the replace function but got the error message: Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function

Thanks

Comment: Please specify the RDBMS that you are targeting by adding the appropriate tag (Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, etc.). There may be answers that take advantage of language or product features that are not universally supported. Also, by tagging it with a specific RDBMS, your question may receive attention from people better suited to answer it.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server 2008R2:

```
SELECT REPLACE(@mystring,'|',',') + ' ' + REPLACE(LEFT(@mystring,CHARINDEX(' ',@mystring)-1),'|',',')
```

replacing `@mystring` with the name of your field.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL:

```
Select Replace(colName,"|",",")
```

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Thanks jlareau for your answer. Can you please advise how to the copy the chars before the first space in the string to the end so the resultant text will be like this: X1,Y1 X2,Y2 X3,Y3 X4,Y4 X5,Y5 X1,Y1

Comment: I don't know about SQL Server, but this works in MySQL: Select Replace(Concat(colName, " ",Left(colName, Locate(" ",colName) )) , "|", ",");

Comment: I apologize for editing the question after posting. Just I realized the question is not exactly as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use ***REPLACE*** with blob fields, you should convert it first to string field
try this:

```
select replace(replace(cast(a as nvarchar(max)) + ' ' + left(cast(a as nvarchar(max)),
      charindex(' ', cast(a as nvarchar(max))) - 1),' ',','),'|',' ')
from aaa
```